# На компьютере слайдер работает, при загрузке на гитхаб - нет

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, jcarousel

```css
.carousel {
    height: 500px;
}
.carousel .item {
    height: 500px;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
.carousel-caption h4 {
    font-size: 300%;
}
.carousel-caption h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 6rem;
    font-family: "Ametist", cursive;
}
.carousel-caption h1 span {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 4rem;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-10 slider">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <!-- carousel -->
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img src="images_1/Slide_2.jpg" alt="Адаптивный дизайн для сайта">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-grain"></span> Конфеты "Рафаэлло" <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-grain"></span></h1>
                                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-opacity" href="Dessert_recepies/Dessert_2.html" role="button">Узнать рецепт</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="images_1/Slide_1.jpg" alt="Адаптивные элементы для сайта">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-grain"></span> Маффины <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-grain"></span></h1>
                                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-opacity" href="Bake_recepies/Bake_8.html" role="button">Узнать рецепт</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="images_1/Slide_3.jpg" alt="Адаптивные шаблоны для сайта">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-grain"></span> Орешки <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-grain"></span></h1>
                                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-opacity" href="Dessert_recepies/Dessert_8.html" role="button">Узнать рецепт</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
                </div>
                <!-- /.carousel -->
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: https://cdn.rawgit.com/Annelia55/Sweet-recepies/master/Index.html
(здесь можно увидеть неработающий слайдер)

Comment: в общем http://atmpl....  это ссылка на ucoz который не отдаёт по ссылке на свой jquery вот как раз и ошибку показывает в console , но сладер работает после того как я указал http:// и потом заработало

Comment: и кстати мне понравился ваш слайдер - красиво и не обычно , особенно надпись которая крутится, вот ваша исправленная вёрстка кроме jimbotron :  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOmpGp?editors=110

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Не работает потому, что у вас **HTTPS** соединение, а скрипты подключаются через **HTTP**.

Если ваш сайт работает по HTTPS, весь активный контент (скрипты, фреймы), отправленный по HTTP, будет заблокирован. Следовательно, сайт может начать работать неправильно. Пассивный контент (картинки, видео) пока что загружается, однако пользователь может заблокировать в настройках и его.

Подробно можете прочитать: [Тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Security/MixedContent/FixMixedContent)

А для корректной работы Вам следует **заменить**:

```
<link href="http://atmpl.ru/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://atmpl.ru/design/adaptive-slider/2015/bootstrap-atmpl/slider-bootstrap-slideSequence.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://atmpl.ru/assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://atmpl.ru/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**На**:

```
<link href="//atmpl.ru/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//atmpl.ru/design/adaptive-slider/2015/bootstrap-atmpl/slider-bootstrap-slideSequence.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//atmpl.ru/assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//atmpl.ru/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]